# Linq lambda for Date between d1 and d2 giving me grief?

Tags: linq, datetime

When debugging, the incoming values for these 3 *DateTime* types are:

```
CreatedDate = 2/3/2012 3:11:34 PM
d1 =  1/1/2012 12:00:00 AM
d2 = 2/3/2012 12:00:00 AM

listings = listings.Where(d=>d.CreatedDate >= d1.Date && d.CreatedDate <= d2.Date);
```

I have data in the listings var until after this expression; any clues on why they are not shown?

Comment: your created date looks to outside of the range you've specificed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

d2.Date is not greater than d.CreatedDate

Comment: sigh...i gotta go to bed. Thank you....I have to wait 9 min to mark this answered...ty again.

Comment: Hah no worries. Sometimes it just takes another set of eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    Get<Collection>()
                               .Where(
x => x.ModifiedInfo.Peek().DateCreated >= DateTime.Parse("2016-11-11") 
 && x.ModifiedInfo.Peek().DateCreated <= DateTime.Parse("2016-11-16") )
                                                               .Dump();
```